# Problem with my Macbook Pro Charger

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, charger

I was working on my Macbook pro and suddenly we lost electricity, and while the electricity was out my charger was connected to the laptop. Now that electricity came back my adaptor stopped charging my laptop. I checked its wire and everything looks fine. Anything I can do beside buying a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes when Electricity is turned back on by the power company, there is something called the surge.

It is a high Voltage spike, very, very short, and most appliance will survive, but some wont.

Aside of getting new charger, please buy a surge protector to prevent that happening again.

If you want to make sure it is dead, use a Volt meeter and check the chargers output pins.

Comment: Ooops so I'm done with this charger then :P

Comment: It looks that way, as said, to make sure use a Volt meter and check its output.